# why cout statement is not working after pointer initialization?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, cout

cout statement is not working after pointer initialization. And this code gives me a segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *p;
  *p=12;

  cout<<"NOW THIS STATEMENT WILL NOT WORK";//BUT WHY?
  cout<<*p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: answer-just get to know that "a pointer stores the address" so if you will try to initialize the value directly then it wont happen as in that case pointer doesn't have the address of that value and even the value is not stored at any address...so first we need to store that value in a variable so that we can use it through pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt initialize the pointer:

```
int *p;
```

`p` points "nowhere", it is not initialized, its value is indeterminate. When you dereference it in the next line:

```
*p=12;
```

You cause undefined behavior, because `p` does not point to an `int`. There is no `int` where you could store `12`.

If you want to store an `int` somewhere, you need an `int` not just a pointer to an `int`:

```
int x = 0;
int *p = &x;
*p=12;       // same as x = 12;
```